# greendao DaoException Entity has no key

Tags: greendao

Using GreenDao, I've somehow managed to put my db in a state where I have an entity that has no key.

My questions is how do I clear / delete this entity?  I didn't see a function in the AbstractDao that will let me delete on another column name.

Comment: I'm skeptical that you were able to actually insert an entity with a null primary key. How did you verify that the entity you inserted has no primary key? Please paste some code spinets of what code is executing and what error/exception is being thrown.

Comment: you can insert an entity w/ null primary key but it will be attached a primary key right after insert. to delete entity, you can use DeleteQuery.

Comment: @yigit thanks for clarifying that. Directly from [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), `If an INSERT statement attempts to insert a NULL value into a rowid or integer primary key column, the system chooses an integer value to use as the rowid automatically.`

Comment: I'm just doing a standard GreenDao insert, nothing less, nothing more.  I came upon this error by testing on a crappy old, low end android device w/ a large listview and inserted and deleted very rapidly.  i inserted / deleted using transactions but still got there.  I can't reproduce error on more modern android devices, so haven't investigated further b/c its so isolated and unfortunately there are too many other pressing things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a raw SQL-query to delete the row and execute it using the SQLiteDatabase that you can get from your readable DaoSession.

```
DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE someColumn=?
```

If you want to avoid typos you can use tableinformation from greendao:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + YourDao.TABLENAME +
               " WHERE " + YourDao.Properties.SomeColumn.columnName + "=?";
```

---

**For further information:**

Depending on how you created your schema, there are some pitfalls:

If you created the primary key with `AUTOINCREMENT` and `NOT NULL` greendao will not insert the primary key correctly!

Insted of assigning an autoincremented primary key, the primary key will always be `0` resulting in an contraint violation upon inserting a second row into the table.

Therefore you shouldn't use `notNull().primaryKey().autoincrement()`, if you don't want to have to deal with greendao-sourcecode.

I have made some minor changes to greendao-core to be able to use the upper statement, but everything should work well, if only use `primaryKey().autoincrement()`.

Comment: just fyi - added comment to above re: how i got there

Answer (score 0):

Primary key is itself unique and not null and even if I mention it explicitly (not null().primaryKey()) , it should work flawlessly. I want to point out, whether am I doing wrongly or is there a fault in greenDAO. 
Is there any word from greenDAO to resolve the issue in the upcoming releases.

I did not have much reputation otherwise i would have asked it in a comment.